# integrating product of PDF and CDF

Tags: integration, probability-theory

I am trying to show that the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a F(x)~f(x)~dx = \frac{F(a)}{2!}
$$
Where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of some continuous random variable X, and $f$ is the probability density function. Not quite sure how this conclusion was reached?

Comment: are you missing a power of two off the right hand side? or is there some context missing about the distributions?

Comment: I agree with @Chinny84: are you sure the result isn't supposed to be $\frac{(F(a))^{2}}{2}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clearly $F'(x)=f(x)$ (wherever CDF is continuous).

Substitute $F(x)=t$. Then $dt=f(x)dx$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^a F(x)~f(x)~dx \rightarrow \int_{0}^{F(a)} t~dt= \frac{(F(a))^2}{2}$$

Comment: Is there similar result possible for $\int_{-\infty}^a F(x)~f(x+b)~dx$ ?

Comment: I am curious: What is the significance of taking the product of the PDF and CDF? Then, I believe the integral take all possible values?